# Text goes outside of the page

Tags: lists, pdf

I am writing a list of demonstrations but when the description of the demonstration is too long in the pdf file it goes outside of the page

[image]

The part of code is the following:

```
    \documentclass{article}





\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{ mathrsfs }
\usepackage[margin=0.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}


\newcounter{enumcounter} 

\newcounter{proofcount}[enumcounter]

\newenvironment{myenumerate}{\begin{description}\stepcounter{enumcounter}}{\end{description}}
% defined a new environment, which uses description instead of enumerate or itemize, to avoid the pre-existing
% counters. The spacing is not identical, granted.

\newcommand*{\itemproof}{\item\addtocounter{proofcount}{1}[\theproofcount] }

\begin{document}

\begin{myenumerate}
\itemproof \colorbox{green}{Dimostrare le principali proprietà di una misura: misura del vuoto, additività finita, monotonia, continuità per insiemi inscatolati (1) e (2), sub-additività.}
\end{myenumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: From your code's fragment is not possible to figured out what is cause of your problem. Please provide MWE (Minimal Working Example, a small complete document beginning with \documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`, which reproduce your problem.)

Comment: `\colorbox` is like `\mbox` and so does not allow lline breaking unless you nest a parbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simpler solution based on `enumitem`: I create a `prooflist`, of type `enumerate`, which has automatically its own counter, `prooflisti`. For the coloured boxes, I iinsert them in a `\parbox` of the relevant width.

```
\documentclass[italian]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{amssymb}%
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{ mathrsfs }
\usepackage[margin=0.9in, showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
%
\usepackage{calc}
\newlist{prooflist}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[prooflist]{label =[\arabic*], wide=0pt, leftmargin=*}

\newcommand*{\itemproof}{\item\addtocounter{proofcount}{1}[\theproofcount] }

\begin{document}

\begin{prooflist}
\item \colorbox{SeaGreen!60}{\parbox[t]{\linewidth-2\fboxsep}{Dimostrare le principali proprietà di una misura: misura del vuoto, additività finita, monotonia, continuità per insiemi ins\-catolati (1) e (2), sub-additività.}}
\item Dimostrare le principali proprietà di una misura: misura del vuoto, additività finita, monotonia, continuità per insiemi inscatolati (1) e (2), sub-additività.
\end{prooflist}

\end{document}
```

[image]